# jQuery "unstick" box when scrolling before a certain threshold

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a box that needs to stick, and I am using `position: fixed` CSS for that when it reaches the bottom of the page while scrolling, and then unstick while scrolling back up past that threshold. Below is my jQuery code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var wHeight = $(window).height();
  var stickyTop = $('.threshold').offset().top;
  var xxx = stickyTop - wHeight;
  var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  if ( windowTop > xxx ) {
    console.log(windowTop)
    $('.box').addClass("sticky")
  } else {
    $('.box').removeClass("sticky")
  }
});
```

I don't understand why my `else` state doesn't work. And it's weird that the `console.log` kicks in late.

Here's a complete pen: https://codepen.io/frontend2020/pen/vYjJBma?editors=1010

Thanks for helping!

Comment: So when you scroll upit should immediately jump to the top of the page? Even if the user only scrolls up 10px? and if they then scroll down 5px, should the box immediately jump down into the sticky area?

Comment: @cloned no actually it goes back to static when  ( windowTop < xxx )

Answer (score 0):

This kind of sticking effect can be easily done with CSS. If you want something similar like this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_DIDQXUx2Y) which was captured on [this site](https://www.myanmarhouse.com.mm/properties/522/4th-floor-mini-condo-with-wide-view-of-main-road-near-taung-ukkala-vip-area), you just need two nested divs (i.e.`div`>`div`).

The parent div must has larger height (let's say `1000px`) and child div can be anything less than the parent div (let's say `200px`). Then you just need to apply `position: sticky;` to child div.

That will do the trick.